# Using Temp File Method for signing in iText Java instead of depending on System Memory

Tags: itext

We are using PKCS7 Signatures and are signing a document on the server using a signature created on the client. We are creating Pdf Objects in memory, and want to switch to a system where we do not need to depend on system memory. Currently, I am saving the PdfSignatureAppearance Object created while generating hash in session,and then using this object from session when I receive a response from client (Signed Hash Content). Could you please help me figure out a way through which I do not need to save the PdfSignatureAppearance object in session and can directly use the Temp File for signing?

First, we generate a hash of file after inserting signature appearance as shown in the code below:

```
File file = new File("To be signed file location")
char version = '\u0000'
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
String outputFile = "Signed file name"
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(file.absolutePath))
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, out, version, true)
PdfFormField pdfFormField = PdfFormField.createSignature(stamper.getWriter())
String signatureName = "Signature1"
pdfFormField.setWidget(new Rectangle((float) 20, (float) 20, (float) 100, (float) 60), (PdfName) null)
pdfFormField.setFlags(4)
pdfFormField.put(PdfName.DA, new PdfString("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g"))
pdfFormField.setFieldName(signatureName)
pdfFormField.setPage(1)
stamper.addAnnotation(pdfFormField, i)
stamper.close()
pdfReader = new PdfReader(out.toByteArray())
stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfReader, fileOutputStream, version, (File) null, true)
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance()
appearance.setLayer2Text("Digitally Signed by Name")
appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(esignRequestCO.logoLocation))
appearance.setAcro6Layers(true)
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime(new Date())
cal.add(12, 5)
appearance.setSignDate(cal)
appearance.setVisibleSignature(signatureName)
int contentEstimated = 16384
HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap()
exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, contentEstimated * 2 + 2)
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
dic.setReason(appearance.getReason())
dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation())
dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()))
appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic)
appearance.preClose(exc)
InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream()
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inp)
String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(bytes)
```

As soon as we get the signed content, we insert the content in the file using same appearance object as shown below:

```
int contentEstimated = 16384
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = "PdfSignatureAppearance object from session generated in previous step"
byte[] p7barray = "signed content here".bytes
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated]
System.arraycopy(p7barray, 0, paddedSig, 0, p7barray.length)
PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary()
dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, (new PdfString(paddedSig)).setHexWriting(true))
appearance.close(dic2)
```

Comment: Please indicate the iText version you are using. It clearly isn't a 7.x, but which 5.x (or even 2.x?) is it?

Comment: We are using itextpdf version 5.5.12.

Comment: In that case you should look for a `MakeSignature.signDeferred` use case, e.g. [C4_09_DeferredSigning.java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4#881-c4_09_deferredsigning.java).